# How can search with and without space using elasticsearch

Tags: search, elasticsearch, lucene, full-text-search

I am having field name **RAM** which contains values like 2 GB , 3 GB and all.

So if a user searches for 2GB phones( without space) ,Elasticsearch is not giving any result.

How can I achieve this feature in ES?

Do I have to index data as **2 GB** and **2GB** both ?

Also I am having another field named screen size having values as **5 inch,7 inch**.

So If user searches for 5 inch phones with 2 GB ram is only giving result for only 5 inch and not searching for both items.

My query is like below.

```
 {
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match": { 
          "_all": {
            "query": "2 GB ram phones with 5 inch screen"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Depends if your data field is analyzed or not. When you type "2GB" it is treated as "2GB" , but if you type "2 GB" this breaks it into two tokens as "2" & "GB" , what you can do is do make ur fields analyzed and then search as *2GB*

Comment: So I have to index both 2GB and 2 GB?